# C++ - using a 2D array of which the dimension is [250][12]

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, multidimensional-array

I have a CSV file which contains 250 lines and each line contains 12 items separated by commas. I am going to store this in a 2D array of which the dimension is [250][12].

My question is : " Is it a bad programming practice to use such a huge array ?
                   I am going to pass this array to a method which takes a 2D array as the argument. It comes with openCV.
                   will there be a memory overflow ? "

Comment: Are you asking because you believe the entire array will be copied when passed into the function?

Comment: 250x12 is not very big.  Unless each array element is huge, you're not going to have any issues with memory.

Comment: What are the items types?

Comment: It seems unlikely that OpenCV has a function that takes a 2-D array of strings with width 12, what function exactly are you planning to call?

Comment: If a double has 8 bytes and if it is an array of doubles, then the array of dim 250*12, having 3000 entries, consumes 24 kiB. That's not huge.

Comment: 250x12 is not big. Are you planning on putting it on the heap?

Comment: What are the items? In total the array will have 3000 items, so unless each item requires > 1 MB of storage, there will not be a problem.

Comment: That is a tiny, wee, ever so slight, lilliputian fairy of an array.

Comment: I'm referring to SVM.train(). It actually needs a matrix.and, it should be given as a 2D array...ryt ?

Comment: all the items are of type "double"

Comment: @JohnB This is what drives me crazy about the campaign to brainwash people into using the pathetic "kibibyte" and similar terms: the victims inevitably use those terms even when they really do want decimal prefixes, as you just did. 250*12*8 is 24000, which is 24 decimal kilobytes, which rounds to 23 binary kilobytes.

Comment: @Boann: I'm deeply sorry. You're absolutely right.

Comment: @JohnB I appreciate the apology. I shouldn't have sounded so condescending. It just drives me crazy; sometimes I'll hear someone quote the size of their hard disk in "gibibytes" .. even though they haven't converted the number from the one on the box, and hard disks are literally the *only* things that really are measured in decimal units.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't have to use it, it would be better. For example, read the file line by line and enter each line into the csv parser. That way each line is dealt with, and you rely on the (hopefully professional and optimized) memory management.

However, if it works it works. If you don't need this in a production environment, I don't see why you should have to change it, other than good practice.

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what you mean. "Better", why? In what sense?

Comment: In general, processors are really fast, and we have a lot of memory on computers these days. However the limiting factor in computer speed is memory. So if you can go for a less memory intensive option, it's better in my opinion. In a case like this, there's a chance the software you are using can make an assumption about the data that you may not, which allows them to be more memory efficient. In general, if you can rely on trusted systems or software to do your work, do it. It helps minimize your work.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. It's about storing the data array after it's been read and parsed, not storing the file in memory before reading and parsing.

Comment: What is the function that the data is being passed to? Is it possible to 'queue' up the data? For example, setupAction(1) may append to an internal array and startAction() might start the actual processing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to be clear about how you'll break a line of text into 12 fields typed as expected by openCV. You may want that to be the central area of the design.

No problem using a static array if the size 250x12 will never change and memory consumption is suitable for the hardware your program is supposed to run on. You face a trade-off between memory usage and complexity of code: if memory is a concern or if you have flexibility in mind then you should process line by line or even token by token, provided openCV implements those modes.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the size of the array is going to be limited to 250*12 then that is not a huge array, assuming you are using a reasonable machine. Even with long double type elements your array is going to take 36 MB of space. If, however, your underlying elements are objects with sub-elements then you may want to re-think your approach e.g., processing the array row-by-row or element-by-element instead of reading it into the memory all at once.

As for passing the array to the function, you will not pass the array by value, you will pass a pointer to the array so it should not be a big overhead.

Comment: 250*12*12 is 35 kilobytes, not 36 megabytes. You were off by a factor of ~1048.